# Does Angular NavigationBehaviorOptions state paramter have a maximum size?

Tags: javascript, angular

So i have this app where I'm getting data from my server and I want to display the result in a separate route. I tried using this line of code to send the data

```
.subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result)
    this.router.navigate(['/results'], { state: { data: result } });
  });
```

The result here is an array of objects.
The interesting thing is that when I use my small test object, which is an array of 3 objects, it works flawlessly. But when I try using a real result, which has about 21000 objects, I get an error. The only difference is the size of the result. I haven't found anything in the docs about a maximum size, so I was hoping somebody would be able to help me out

Edit:

The error message is (running on the ng serve dev server):

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [Exception... "Illegal value"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:4200/vendor.js :: pushState :: line 766
```

After that I get a very long stack trace.

Comment: Is the error supposed to be a secret? Please share as many details as possible.

Comment: Sorry I edited the post with the error. It has a huge stack trace, so i wasnt sure if i should post the full thing

Comment: Are you sure the problem happens here? What is on line 766? Maybe your component at `/results` cant handle the results? You could also save the result to a service and then navigate away. OnInit at `/results` load data from service. I doubt this is the case but could be that on such a large data set some anomalies happen during navigation.

Comment: After hours of googling I think what happens is that this method is using the history API and it has a maximum size of 2 MiB which this exceeds.

The /results works perfectly fine.This is just me trying split up my code into several routes. Until now i was using ngIf statements to make the component show up dynamically, and it worked perfectly fine